# Hellsing Ultimate music theme in episode 8

Tags: music, hellsing

I am looking for the music theme which plays during Alucard's zero level release, while the Major is singing (talking). Can you please help me find it?

The music starts at around 0:50 in this video: [Hellsing's Zero Release](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YODvtc7-qk8&t=50)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will be Letzte Bataillon from the Hellsing OVA I-V Soundtrack “Nazi CD”. It's listed as song number 2.